# Time difference between manually entered time and datetimestamp field

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a datetime field: PAYCOM_IN_TIME

I also have a manually entered field (ex: '07:00:00'): SCHEDULED_CLOCK_IN
SCHEDULED_CLOCK_IN is built using this in my query:
SELECT '07:00:00' SCHEDULED_CLOCK_IN FROM DUAL

I wish to get the time difference in MINUTES: PAYCOM_IN_TIME minus SCHEDULED_CLOCK_IN

[image]

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  What i s the data type of `scheduled_clock_in`?  And why are you using square braces?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I converted my hh:mm:ss text entry to a datetimestamp:
to_date(to_char(PAYCOM_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY') || S.CLOCK_IN, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Then I calculated Minutes:
(SCHEDULED_CLOCK_IN - P.CLOCKIN) * 24 * 60 DIFF_MINS

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT paycom_in_time,
       scheduled_clock_in,
       ( TRUNC( paycom_in_time ) + scheduled_clock_in - paycom_in_time ) DAY TO SECOND
         AS difference_interval,
       ROUND(
         ( TRUNC( paycom_in_time ) + scheduled_clock_in - paycom_in_time )
         * 24 * 60
       ) AS difference_minutes
FROM   table_name
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE AS scheduled_clock_in FROM DUAL
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( paycom_in_time ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-10-17' + INTERVAL '07:49' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-10-13' + INTERVAL '06:51' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-10-22' + INTERVAL '06:56' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-10-23' + INTERVAL '06:47' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-10-26' + INTERVAL '06:52' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-10-30' + INTERVAL '06:59' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> PAYCOM_IN_TIME      | SCHEDULED_CLOCK_IN | DIFFERENCE_INTERVAL | DIFFERENCE_MINUTES
> :------------------ | :----------------- | :------------------ | -----------------:
> 2020-10-17 07:49:00 | +00 07:00:00       | -00 00:49:00.000000 |                -49
> 2020-10-13 06:51:00 | +00 07:00:00       | +00 00:09:00.000000 |                  9
> 2020-10-22 06:56:00 | +00 07:00:00       | +00 00:04:00.000000 |                  4
> 2020-10-23 06:47:00 | +00 07:00:00       | +00 00:13:00.000000 |                 13
> 2020-10-26 06:52:00 | +00 07:00:00       | +00 00:08:00.000000 |                  8
> 2020-10-30 06:59:00 | +00 07:00:00       | +00 00:01:00.000000 |                  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56ff9d34e6fa48532f5a0a99438fec65)*

Answer (score -1):

Use a query with
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(paycom, shedulded))/60;

Or

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, paycom, shedulded) AS [Time in Minutes]

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL.  DATEDIFF and TIME_TO_SEC aren't available.